# How to iterate through Redis Hashes and Sets?

Tags: redis

My query consists of a combination of REDIS Hashes + Sets. I have created a set of 4 hashes. My data structure is as below:

**cache:0** 
"prod_color"
"Red"

"prod_count"
"12"

"prod_price"
"200.00"

**cache:1**
"prod_color"
"Red"

"prod_count"
"12'

"prod_price"
"200.00"

**cache:2**
"prod_color"
"Red"

"prod_count"
"12'

"prod_price"
"200.00"

**cache:3**
"prod_color"
"Red"

"prod_count"
"12'

"prod_price"
"200.00"

I have created 4 hashes i.e. cache:0,cache:1,cache:2,cache:3 which are members of the set 'cache'. My goal is to write a REDIS script using the existing commands.

The task is to iterate through all the four sets:

> If prod_color = "Red" display the entire record

i.e using the HGETALL command(i.e "Red","12","200.00")

I went through the entire command set for hashes but have not been able to write a script/set of commands for my task.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know redis doesn't have any kind of logic commands which would allow you to evaluate the key values based on some statements. You probably need to use some scripting/programming language which would allow you to evaluate and manipulate the raw data you get out of redis.